# AVFoundation camera image quality degraded upon processing

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I made an AVFoundation camera to crop square images based on @fsaint answer: [Cropping AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer output to a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014651/cropping-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-output-to-a-square) . The sizing of the photo is great, that works perfectly. However the image quality is noticeably degraded (See Below: first image is preview layer showing good resolution, second is the degraded image that was captured). It definitely has to do with what happens in `processImage:` as the image resolution is fine without it, just not the right aspect ratio. The documentation on image processing is pretty bare, any insights are GREATLY appreciated!!

Setting up camera:

```
func setUpCamera() {

      captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
      captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
      let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
      if ((backCamera?.hasFlash) != nil) {
         do { 
            try backCamera.lockForConfiguration()
            backCamera.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto
            backCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
         } catch {
            // error handling
         }
      }
      var error: NSError?
      var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
      do {
         input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
      } catch let error1 as NSError {
         error = error1
         input = nil
      }
      if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
         captureSession!.addInput(input)
         stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
         stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
         if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            previewVideoView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            captureSession!.startRunning()
         }
      }
   }
```

Snapping photo:

```
@IBAction func onSnapPhotoButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

      if let videoConnection = self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
         videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
self.stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in

            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {

               let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
               let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
               let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

               let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)   
               self.processImage(image)
               self.clearPhotoButton.hidden = false
               self.nextButton.hidden = false
               self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.imageView)
            }
         })
      }
   }
```

Process image to square:

```
  func processImage(image:UIImage) {

      let deviceScreen = previewLayer?.bounds
      let width:CGFloat = (deviceScreen?.size.width)!
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, width))
      let aspectRatio:CGFloat = image.size.height * width / image.size.width
      image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, -(aspectRatio - width) / 2.0, width, aspectRatio))
      let smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      let cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)
      let imageRef:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(smallImage.CGImage, cropRect)!
      imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
   }
```

[image: previewLater]

[image: processed image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are a few things wrong with your `processImage()` function.

First of all, you're creating a new graphics context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`.

[According to the Apple docs on this function:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext)

> This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a **scale factor of 1.0.**

Because the scale factor is `1.0`, it is going to look pixelated when displayed on-screen, as the screen's resolution is (most likely) higher.

**You want to be using the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` function, and pass `0.0` for the scale factor.** According to the docs on this function, for the `scale` argument:

> If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

**For example:**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, width), NO, 0.0);
```

Your output should now look nice and crisp, as it is being rendered with the **same scale** as the screen.

---

**Second of all, there's a problem with the width you're passing in.**

```
let width:CGFloat = (deviceScreen?.size.width)!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, width))
```

You shouldn't be passing in the width of the screen here, it should be the width of the *image*. For example:

```
let width:CGFloat = image.size.width
```

You will then have to change the `aspectRatio` variable to take the screen width, such as:

```
let aspectRatio:CGFloat = image.size.height * (deviceScreen?.size.width)! / image.size.width
```

---

**Third of all, you can simplify your cropping function significantly.**

```
func processImage(image:UIImage) {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

    let width:CGFloat = image.size.width
    let height:CGFloat = image.size.height

    let aspectRatio = screenWidth/width;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenWidth), false, 0.0) // create context
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, (screenWidth-(aspectRatio*height))*0.5) // shift context up, to create a sqaured 'frame' for your image to be drawn in

    image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin:CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width:screenWidth, height:height*aspectRatio))) // draw image

    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageView.image = img
}
```

There's no need to draw the image twice, you only need to just translate the context up, and then draw the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response @originaluser2! I tried your solution, and the image resolution is sharp, however the image is now very zoomed in. Any ideas on why this happening like this? Thanks again!

Comment: @tahoecoop yes, I just noticed you're creating the context with the size of the screen, not the size of the image. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I tried your edit. Unfortunately it's still zooming in similar to what it was doing before. Am I messing up the sizing when I use ` let cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)`? Thanks again!!

Comment: @tahoecoop ah yes, actually you should simply change the `width` variable to the image width, and then adjust your `aspectRatio` variable to take the screen width.

Comment: @tahoecoop actually, I've just re-worked your function and it should now do what you want it to do.

Comment: You are the man! Your `processImage:` does the trick perfectly. Really appreciate the help, this is awesome!!